# import statement returns module member as undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

Module (`./lib/myModule.js`):

```
const X = 10;

export default { X }
```

---

Main module (`./index.js`):

**Case 1:**

```
import { X } from './lib/myModule'

console.log(X) // undefined
```

**Case 2:**

```
import myModule from './lib/myModule'

const { X } = myModule;

console.log(myModule.X) // 10
console.log(X) // 10
```

Why when using object matching notation returns `X` as undefined and importing full object the member keeps his value? What's wrong with first case?

I'm using Babel for transforming ES 6 code with `preset-es2015`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the import statement doesn't use destructuring assignment. In the first case you're trying to import member `X`, which is not exported. In the second case, you're importing the default member and then extracting `X` from it using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

In the first case Babel transforms the `console.log()` line to this:

```
console.log(_myModule.X); // undefined
```

Whereas in the second case you get this:

```
console.log(_myModule2.default.X);
```

Comment: import statement doesn't use destructuring assignment? It's a little bit confuse to me how works this module pattern with `export default`. Using as not `default` so only `export { X }` and `import { X } from './lib/myModule` is working as intended. You can explain why `X` is not exported in first case and how could I do?

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi In the first case you're exporting as default an object with `'X'` property set to the `X` variable. If you export without `default` (i.e. `export { X }`) you're exporting the `X` variable as `'X'` (you're not exporting an object here).